# Multiplicity vs Partition function

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy, partition-function

I'm a little confused between all the different notations for the multiplicity and partition function. They're not the same thing, are they?
I know that entropy can be expressed as

$ S = k \ln\Omega $

or

$ S = k\ln Q + kT \frac{\partial \ln(Q)}{\partial T} $

in terms of multiplicity and partition function respectively. They look like they could be related. What is the relationship?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the limit that $T\rightarrow\infty$, the partition function and the multiplicity of states are equal.

Why? Well, we have that $Q=\sum_{i} e^{-E_i/kT}$, where $i$ indexes all possible microstates. If $T\rightarrow\infty$, these Boltzman factors all approach one, and we have $Q=\sum_i 1=\Omega$.

You might think that in the limit $T\rightarrow\infty$ the two formulas you gave above would badly disagree, since there's an extra term proportional to $T$ in your second formula. But if you do the derivative explicitly, you'll find that the $\frac{\partial \ln(Q)}{\partial T}$ is proportional to $\frac{1}{T^2}$, so that the term $kT\frac{\partial \ln(Q)}{\partial T}$ goes to zero as $T\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: could you please elaborate on how $ Q = \sum_i 1 = \Omega $ ? I have a pretty good understanding of what multiplicity is from combinatorial point of view, but I'm not sure how exactly it relates to the partition function in this case or otherwise.

Comment: @Solarmew in the partition function, the sum $i$ runs over all possible microstates of the system (you get one Boltzman factor for each microstate). So if you do the sum $\sum_i 1$ you get the total number of microstates, $\Omega$.

Comment: @Solarmew and the first equality $Q=\sum_i 1$ just comes from taking the $T\rightarrow\infty$ limit of $Q=\sum_i e^{-E_i/kT}$.

Answer (score 4):

> They look like they could be related. What is the relationship?

From your two equations, we have

$$k\ln \Omega = k \ln Q + kT\frac{\partial}{\partial T} \ln Q = k \ln Q + \frac{kT}{Q}\frac{\partial}{\partial T}Q$$

but

$$Q = \sum_ie^{-\frac{E_i}{kT}}$$

and so

$$k\ln \Omega = k \ln Q + \frac{kT}{Q}\frac{1}{kT^2}\sum_i E_ie^{-\frac{E_i}{kT}} = k\left(\ln Q + \frac{1}{kT} \langle E \rangle \right)$$

Dividing through by $k$ and exponentiating both sides yields:

$$\Omega = Qe^{\frac{\langle E \rangle}{kT}}$$

Comment: I meant conceptually :] I feel like I don't have a very good grasp on what a partition function actually is %\

Answer (score 1):

There is a little known fact that is relevant here.  The energies of microstates are only specified up to an arbitrary additive constant (as with all energies, which are always referenced to a zero of the energy).  For example, it is common in statistical mechanics to reference all microstate energies relative to the energy of the lowest energy microstate.  A constant energy can be added or substracted from all microstate energies without changing the probabilities of the microstates:

\begin{align}
\require{cancel}
   E_i' &= E_i - C \\
    p_i &= \frac{e^{-\beta E_i'}}{\sum_s e^{-\beta E_i'}}
        =  \frac{e^{-\beta (E_i-C)}}{\sum_s e^{-\beta (E_i-C)}}
        =  \frac{e^{\beta C} e^{-\beta E_i}}{\sum_s e^{\beta C} e^{-\beta E_i}}
        =  \frac{\cancel{e^{\beta C}} e^{-\beta E_i}}{\cancel{e^{\beta C}} \sum_s e^{-\beta E_i}}
\end{align}

Now, as Alfred Centauri states, the multiplicity and partition function are related by:

$$\Omega = Qe^{\beta \langle E \rangle}$$

If, however, one normalizes the microstate energies so that the average energy $\langle E' \rangle = 0$ ($E_i' = E_i - \langle E \rangle$), we have:

$$\Omega = Q$$

exactly.